# Quoting selected text using email conventions?

Tags: text-editing, email, formatting

Is there any existing elisp function which will quote any selected text using email quoting conventions?

For example, suppose the following text appears in a buffer ...

```
This is some text that
I want to quote, using
email quoting conventions.

And this is a bit more text
which I also want to be quoted
in the same manner.
```

I'd like to select this text and run some sort of function which will cause it to appear as follows:

```
> This is some text that
> I want to quote, using
> email quoting conventions.
>
> And this is a bit more text
> which I also want to be quoted
> in the same manner.
```

Furthermore, if I select this quoted text and run that same function on it again, I'd like the result to look like this:

```
>> This is some text that
>> I want to quote, using
>> email quoting conventions.
>>
>> And this is a bit more text
>> which I also want to be quoted
>> in the same manner.
```

In other words, I don't want any space to appear between the leading `>` characters in the multiply quoted text.

Are there any existing elisp functions which will do this?

Comment: PS: I know I can write such a function myself. But the reason I posted my question here is that I'd like to know whether such an elisp function already exists, so I don't have to "re-invent the wheel".